# Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope Bad Content-Type of ‘text/html’

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have an angular website that I am trying to setup a service worker for so that the website can be used offline.

When I deploy my app to an Azure service I see this error when the site loads

> Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope ‘my_url’: Bad
>   Content-Type of ‘text/html’ received for script
>   ‘my_url/ngsw-worker.js’.  Must be a JavaScript MIME type.

When I run the angular app locally I dont see this error but I see a warning under Chrome DevTools/Application/Manifest that says

> No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page
>   or check that the service worker for the current page also controls
>   the start url from the manifest

I register my service worker in my app.module imports like this

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, scope: '/'})
```

This is my `ngsw-config,json`

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/index.html",
                    "/manifest.webmanifest",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my first go with a service worker so I am not sure how to fix that error

Comment: It sounds like Azure may be setting the Content-Type response header to "text/html" for your service worker js. You should check the Network tab in DevTools when the service worker js is requested from Azure. See what the Content-Type header is coming back as. You may need to configure Azure differently to set the correct header.